# Remove Google Fonts from parent theme within a child theme

Tags: themes, child-theme, fonts

I'm using a third-party theme with a custom child theme on a website and want to remove the Google Fonts from the parent theme within the child theme's functions.php. This is not working - nothing happens.

```
/**
 * Remove parent theme Google fonts
 */
function remove_parent_theme_google_fonts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'themename_googlefonts-css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'themename_googlefonts-css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_theme_google_fonts', 1);
```

where `themename_googlefonts-css` is the parent theme's id from the stylesheet link.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Removed direct references to specific third-party theme to make this more relevant for other users.

Comment: Are you sure this is the handle? `-css` suffix is being added automatically by WordPress so try omitting it. also `after_setup_theme` doesn't seem like the current event to hook into, try `wp_enqueue_scripts`. You can also play with the priority argument, you have `1` at the moment (default is 10), so try a higher/lower priority. You can also use a plugin called `query monitor` to check the actual CSS handle name

Comment: You are right, I accidentally included the default `-css` suffix. Thanks for the hint! It works with `wp_enqueue_scripts`. And I will check the helpful plugin you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As Buttered_Toast mentioned, I think the hook you want to use is `wp_enqueue_scripts` rather than `after_setup_theme`. Changing the priority is also a good idea to make sure your function trigger after the initial call from the parent theme.

So your function would be:

```
/**
 * Remove Accelerate Google fonts
 */
function remove_accelerate_google_fonts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'accelerate_googlefonts-css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'accelerate_googlefonts-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_accelerate_google_fonts', 50);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, except that the handle is not the correct one. See @Buttered_Toast's comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It works with `wp_enqueue_scripts` and the correct handle without the `-css` suffix. Here is my fully working solution:

```
/**
 * Remove parent theme Google fonts
 */
function remove_parent_theme_google_fonts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'themename_googlefonts' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'themename_googlefonts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_parent_theme_google_fonts', 50);
```